# How to kill current running DoTween sequence in Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dotween

DOTween.Kill api return number of actual tweens killed. but use this api can't kill transform's sequence tweens.

DOTween.Kill (this); or DOTween.Kill (transform); or DOTween.Rewind api all can't kill it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's because you're trying to use the DoTween class itself. Rather, you should be using a reference to the sequence to kill it.

Code below

```
Sequence mySequence = DOTween.Sequence();

//Your code here  
mySequence.Append(transform.DoMove(Vector3.right, 1).SetLoops(2, LoopType.Yoyo))  
.Append(transform.DoMove(Vector3.up, 1).SetLoops(2, LoopType.Yoyo))  
.OnComplete(() => {  
    Debug.Log("Done");
});

mySequence.Kill(); //Kill the sequence.
```

Comment: This saved me many more hours of troubleshooting! Thank you!

Comment: That's a wrong way to do it, you most probably have *Recycle Tweens* and *AutoKill* checked in the settings so there can be a case where you kill another tween because your tween has already been completed and recycled into another.
Instead you should `.SetTarget(transform)` (or any target you want) at tween/sequence creation and pass this target in a `DOTween.Kill(transform)`

Answer (score 7):

In my case sequence.Kill() does not work， so I tried Dotween.Kill(object targetOrId), it worked, maybe you can have a try.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, reference to the sequence was lost, and because of that mySequence.Kill(); was not able to find and kill the sequence.

The reason it happened was, that I was calling the method that plays mySequence from 2 different parts of my code repeatedly (This did not have a noticeable visual side effect, so I did not notice until I debugged), but I was only killing the last sequence.

So the order of events was:

1. Create a sequence with Sequence mySequence = DOTween.Sequence();
2. (Mistakenly) Create another sequence by calling the same line again. This resulted earlier mySequence reference to be "overridden", "lost" or "unknown" to the class.
3. Call mySequence.Kill(); (This kills mySequence that is created in 2)
4. mySequence created in 1 is like a zombie now. Nothing can find it and kill it.

If this was a regular tween, one "nuclear" way to fix would be calling DOTween.KillAll(); but as I know it does not work on sequences, plus it kills every tween, which you may not want.

So there are 2 options:

1. Make sure you create only one mySequence, before killing. After you kill it, you can create another with the same name. This approach works but has the risk of calling same creation method several times by mistake.
2. Make sure you have one mySequence in your scene at the same time. This is doable with a Singleton Pattern kind of approach.

   ```
   private Sequence sequence;
   private Guid uid;

   private void StartScalingAnimation()
   {            
       if (sequence == null) // only create if there was none before.
       {
           sequence = DOTween.Sequence();
           sequence.Append(transform.DOScale(new Vector2(1.1f, 1.1f), 1)).SetLoops(-1, LoopType.Yoyo);
           Debug.Log("sequence id is:" + sequence.id); 

           //if your sequence gets an id upon creation, you can cache 
           //it and kill it later with that id. In my case, no id was 
           //given automatically at the start, so I created one.

           uid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
           sequence.id = uid;
           Debug.Log("sequence id now:" + sequence.id);
       }

       sequence.Play();            
   }

   private void StopScalingAnimation()
   {
       DOTween.Kill(uid);
       sequence = null;
   }
   ```