# Killing the current DoTween sequence

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dotween

I am trying to run a DoTween and it runs well but when I want to stop it, it does not stop at all, it keeps running till it finishes. I am using the DoTween Sequence to kill it but somehow it is not working. What is the issue?

```
public float prevValue = 0;
Sequence mySequence = DOTween.Sequence ();

    private void Update () {
        UpdateSlider ();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.T)) {
            LerpToThis (90);
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Z)) {
            KillSequence ();

        }
    }

 public void LerpToValue (float newValue) {
        float myValue = prevValue;

            DOTween.To (() => myValue , x => prevValue = x, newValue, 3.0f);

    }

    public void KillSequence () {
        mySequence.Kill ();
    }
```

Comment: as mentioned by @frankhermes: clean up your code, it seems the `ShouldLerp_` and `DurationFading` are not declared. Preferably add the whole class declarateion and make sure, that your example actually is a piece of code that compiles, so that people can help you.

Comment: @IARI thank you, i have cleared it and removed all non-dependencies.

Comment: I answered a similar question here in detail: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214649/how-to-kill-current-running-dotween-sequence-in-unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214649/how-to-kill-current-running-dotween-sequence-in-unity3d)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the fact that your code uses undeclared variables (like `ShouldLerp_`) and on pressing 'T' you call a different method than is shown in your excerpt, I'll assume your `LerpToThis` call also tweens using `DOTween.To`, but when you try to stop tweening you call `mySequence.Kill()` even though that sequence isn't the thing that is doing the tweening. So that's why the tween doesn't stop.

Call `Kill()` on the result of the `DOTween.To()` call, or give that tween an Id and call `DOTween.Kill(id)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

frankhermes has said it all, I'm just elaborating the solution a bit:

Within the `LerpToValue` method, you create a Tween with the line

```
DOTween.To(() => myValue , x => prevValue = x, newValue, DurationFading);
```

The method `DOTween.To` does return an object of type `Tween` on which you can call `Kill`, i.e. first you add a declaration to your class

```
private Tween myTween;
```

Then you store the tween when you create it in `LerpToValue`

```
myTween = DOTween.To (() => myValue , x => prevValue = x, newValue, DurationFading);
```

And finally, in `KillSequence` (which you will want to rename, since, as frank mentioned, there is no sequence used) you call

```
myTween.Kill();
```

You can get rid of the `DOTween.Sequence ()` entirely.